# Select HTML Element Versus Class

Tags: css, css-selectors

Assume I have HTML code like this:

```
<ul class="my-list">
  <li> One </li>
  <li> Two </li>
  <li> Three </li>
</ul>
```

If I wanted to style the `<li>` elements, I could use the following selector in CSS:
`.my-list li {...}`.
The `.my-list` class here ensures I won't change any `<li>` elements for other lists.

Is there any additional benefit or usefulness to adding the same class to each `<li>` element and simply using that as the selector instead, e.g:

`<li class="my-list-item">`

`.my-list-item {...}`

Comment: No, It's the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is because at the end of the day, you are just selecting an element rather than a class or vice-versa.

Unless you are doing something to target specific elements in a list, then adding a class to the li's would be beneficial as then you can make all the .my-list-item red and the .my-list-item--blue blue for example

I could be completely wrong as there might be some more side effects that even I don't know as in it's quicker to select an element rather than a class but even if that is the case, you wouldn't notice anything.